# How do I make sure that a website is loaded NOT from cache

Tags: asp.net, html, caching

My website homepage suupose to look different every time a user loads it.
However, it loads from memory thus looks the same every time.

How can i make sure that it loads the new page and not the cached page?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to that programmatically or not?

Yes - Send HTTP headers that are about cache-control and expires.

No - Press shift before clicking the refresh button...this is to perform a hard reload.

Comment: -1 , please also provide the code for doing such things, or atleast steps of how to do.

Comment: @Zain - What the heck is wrong with you? He even marked it as the correct answer! Anyhow, do I have to hold your hand to help you key out "php cache-control" or "php expires" on the keyboard? wtf is wrong with some guys....

Answer (score 3):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

 Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
}
```

in your code behind.

Comment: its working fine in our application's signin.aspx page since we first time wrote it.

Answer (score 1):

set your request header for caching with Cache-Control: no-cache and response headers as Pragma: no-cache. and expires: